# Date format Query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date-format, eloquent

My query for fetching a data from database is,

```
select mailboxtoolno,DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,'%d %b %Y') as 
date,DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,'%H:%i:%s') as time,mailtype from 
domiciliation_mailbox where reg_id =".$regid." order by id DESC
```

How can i change it to laravel eloquent model,

I have been trying to change it like,

```
 $timeline= mailbox::select('mailboxtoolno','DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,"%d %b %Y") as date','DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,"%H:%i:%s") as time','mailtype')
->where('reg_id', '=',$reg_id )
->paginate(10);
```

But got an error like,

```
Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,"%d %b %Y")' in 'field list'
```

How can i get the correct value in date format in laravel

Comment: you are using date format in select query, that reason for error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raw` statement instead. For example:

```
$user = User::select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))->where('status', '=', 'active');
```

By the way actually, Laravel has mutator for field with DateTime type. So you can select it as normal and format it later. Example;

```
$user = User::find(2);
$date = $user->created_at->format('d M Y'); // you can display it with any format you want with this way.
```

More information read the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Answer (score 3):

Laravel doesn't support complex select expressions, so you have to use [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions). Try in this way:

```
    $timeline= mailbox::select('mailboxtoolno',DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,"%d %b %Y") as date'),DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(maileventdate,"%H:%i:%s") as time'),'mailtype')
->where('reg_id',$reg_id )
->orderBy('id','DESC')
->paginate(10);
```

In order to use `->orderBy()` in this query you would have to set strict modes manually to ommit order by validation. Do it in your `database.php` config database connection array parameters:

```
'strict'    => true,
        'modes'     => [
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],
```

Or set `strict => false` (I won't do it)